# Can the GoogleMaps pod be built within a cocoapod?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, podspec

I'm currently trying to work on a project that contains many heads.
Essentially the premise is to build the entire project into a cocoapod. This project uses other libraries as well but seemingly will not install. Is the Google Maps pod meant to be used in a cocoapod or no?

Comment: I know how to install it into a podfile. I meant, how would I install it within my own cocoapod project. I'm trying to build my project into a cocoapod, when I try to add the GoogleMaps SDK into a podspec it seemingly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , we can Integrate google map using cocoapods , just follow the steps below

1. If you don't have cocoapod installed , first install it

   sudo gem install cocoapods
   2.Create a podfile by opening terminal and go to the directory path to your Xcode project and run the below commands

   pod init
2. Open podfile and add the following podfile into this file

   pod 'GoogleMaps'

   pod 'GooglePlaces'
3. Now install these dependencies into your project by the following commands

   pod install
4. Now you have GoogleMaps dependency is installed in your project . For the further implementation go to the below google developers link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

All the best

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is different: I'm trying to _make_ my own pod and add other pods into it but for some reason with Google Maps it can't be done.